# Why Jackson library internal implementation utilizing the getter call for engendering the Json

Tags: java, jackson

I have the below piece of the code for engendering the Json.

```
class Student {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   public Student(){}
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }
   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public String toString(){
      return "Student [ name: "+name+", age: "+ age+ " ]";
   }
}
```

Now for creating the Json i need to write the code like below.

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mahesh\", \"age\":21}";

      //map json to student
      try{
         Student student = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Student.class);

         System.out.println(student);

         jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(student);

         System.out.println(jsonString);
      }
      catch (JsonParseException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
      catch (JsonMappingException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   }
```

Now why Jackson library internally utilizing the getter method for json engenderment.

Comment: Because getters are the public API of your class, and return the public information that your object offers to the external world, so I guess it makes more sense to use that by default rather than fields, which are private.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the visibility settings of the `ObjectMapper`.

By default these are the visibility settings for `ObjectMapper`

[image]

(If you look at the image, for fields its set to public only i.e. It will only look for public fields)

All you need to do is set visibility for FIELD to be of any type like this ->

`mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);`

Once you do it, `ObjectMapper` will discover fields with `any` visibility.

Comment: In mundane approach, suppose I am endeavoring to utilize the argument constructor and the ToString then it should work. But for this case I have to indite the getter method for this otherwise the construction of the json will not transpire.

Comment: Ahh, I am not sure what you mean by that :/

Comment: It's mean, if you are endeavoring to get the data then is there any different way, if you are not utilizing the getter.

Comment: yeah the solution tells you how to get data without using getters.